# Additional Shipping Fee on COD for Specific Country Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I've a store setup on **Magento 2.2.3**

I use two payment methods: **COD, Credit Card Payment**

There are 2 allowed countries (for example A and B)

For `Country:A` shipping is flat (i.e. 10 USD)

For `Country:B` shipping is calculated according to weight table

What I want: For `Country:A` when user selects `COD` as payment method, additional shipping charges (5 USD) should be charged (i.e. 10 USD + 5 USD = 15 USD)

How do I achieve this in Magento 2.2.3 so that I could set additional shipping charges from admin and User is shown additional charges at front?

Kindly tell me if there's any free existing module/extension available for this.

Comment: Its not for shipping fee but you can add the fee for COD payment method https://magecomp.com/magento-2-payment-fee.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below two free extension for same. If you have helpful.

> https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee
>
> https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_CashOnDelivery

Hope it help!

Comment: thanks for your response ... I've already tried first link (i.e. bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee) .. it works as expected .. ads up extra fee to COD but there's an issue with this module .. it does not display additional fee on frontend (checkout summary) .. it only displays additional charges on admin-side (in order details) .. any help regarding this??

Comment: i also face the same issue have you find any solution @MuhammadShuja

Comment: @divyasekar the second one worked for me, this one: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_CashOnDelivery